# What do these waves mean when scrolling a youtube video?

Tags: video, youtube

Well, recently I noticed that while scrolling the YouTube video, "waves" appear above the slider. What do they mean? I suspect that these are some of the places presented where most people watched a given fragment of the film but I think I'm wrong.

[image]

Comment: _"I suspect that these are some of the places presented where most people watched..."_ You're correct. Google search says: [YouTube’s player gains new features](https://techcrunch.com/2022/05/18/youtubes-player-gains-new-features-including-most-replayed-video-chapters-single-loop-and-more/?guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubWFjcnVtb3JzLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAHWd0CJSf2S6EGiODCaNHgZKM3JLjxGdlQXYd15lAwL4BocfvzGbsJPq6pXC8qkhAvG7QQlaA0_FgAhqROqDtSHBo6LfwLiavoZjiAY3rOho_EgkoyNfkogyW0WvkvbY0YK-Pe_UXVcLCbRu8BpuFq_iVDPi7qEQfUmObmL1xFDk&guccounter=2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it refers to the parts of a video which are the most viewed.

https://9to5google.com/2021/10/11/youtube-ui-test-highlights-most-viewed-video-portions-in-playback-progress-bar-graph/